# Shellscript - How do I exclude file names listed in a particular file from CHOWN execution

Tags: linux, shell, unix, sh

I'm trying using `chown -R user:user /opt/var/test !(file1.php)` to change the ownership of all files except file1.php from the test directory where file1.php is present in one of the subdirectories, but the command above doesn't work, no error but the file doesn't get exclueded.

Also, I have a couple of more files in the same directory and I want to store them in a file exclusionlist.txt and read the file as an array element and pass it to the same command to exclude from the permission change. Any help.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1306122/chown-r-exclude-some-directory)

Comment: Are you sure you are using `bash` and did you enable extended globbing beforehand with `shopt -s extglob` ?

Comment: @MarkSetchell - yeh, I have enabled shopt -s extglob.

still when I pass !(file1.php) the file is not getting excluded from permission change. 

chown -R user:user $( ls -I <file name>) is working but again I want to set add the directory path, that's something isnt working and 2. I want read the file names for exclusion from the file like exclusionlist.txt